# Custom Menu with swipe items

Tags: android, menu, swipe

Currently I'm developing a small app for my parents' business. I'm trying to create a custom menu. I'd like to have something similar to this:

[image]

If you look at it, the screen is divided in two sections. The upper section is just an image and the lower section is the menu. I'd like to achieve this:

If the user places his finger over an item of the menu and swipes to the right, all the items move one position right, and the opposite if the user swipes left.

I'm quite new in this field and I'm not looking for a piece of code. I just want some tips on what to search because I don't know even where to start.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

By what I understood, ViewPager should be able to solve your problem. You hsve it nested in your layout under the main image. Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Does it work if i want to stay in the same activity?

Comment: Yes, it consists of fragments which you will be switching depending on where you swipe.

Comment: Thanks, i'll focus in ViewPager then!

Comment: And a little tip, these images you're loading, be sure to scale them down a bit if needed and store them in cache instead of loading directly from a url or from your local directory as it may cause an OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: Thank you again. I'll do that!